# How to navigating to a specific page on Push Notification tap

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing firebase push notifications in `Xamarin.Forms` using [**`FirebasePushNotificationPlugin`**](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md). Somehow I am getting notifications for android project in `Application` file, along with data

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NOTIFICATION RECEIVED", p.Data);
    var data = p.Data; //Dictionary type
};
```

Based on above data how can I navigate to specific `Page` except `MainPage()`?

This is my App.xaml.cs file in Shared project

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

MainActivity.cs class in Android project

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, intent);
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**:
According to @G.Hakim answer below code always opening `NotificationsPage` without sending notification(Except first time. Only first time opening `MainPage` when executing app). If I click on app it always goes to `NotificationsPage` instead of `MainPage`.

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App(false,null));

    FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NOTIFICATION RECEIVED", p.Data);
        var data = p.Data;
        DependencyService.Get<IToast>().DisplayTost("opened notifications");
        LoadApplication(new App(true, p));
    };
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public App(bool hasNotification = false, object notificationData = null)
{
    if (hasNotification)
    {
        MainPage = new NotificationsPage();
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do it natively

Comment: @G.hakim - I have implemented notifications for _Xamarin.android_ still confused how can I do that in a way so that it would combine easily with Forms. If I am opening Activity1 navitely, how it relates to shared project's `Page`?

Comment: Well initialize your Xamarin forms page in Activity1 and then just push to the page that you want to navigate to.

Comment: How to push page after initializing activity?

Comment: using this  `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());` if you want i can post an example!!

Comment: Here we are loading application. How we can push page? If know that it would be nice.

Comment: Take a look at the answer revert in case of queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by sending `color` key from notification `payload`.

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
{
    if (p.Data.ContainsKey("color"))
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NotificationsPage()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex($"{p.Data["color"]}")
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Note: Above code is working when app open & in background. Not working when app closed. For more information visit [this ticket](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/158).

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very simple you can do it using some trickery:

- First, call the MainActivity from your notification so that you can use the existing xamarin forms loading functionality.
- Then maintain a bool on your App class constructor something like this:

  ```
  public App(bool hasNotification=false,object notificationData=null)
  {
     if(hasNotification)
     {//case where you receive a notification} // call your normal functionality here 
     else
     {//case where you do not recieve a notification} // notification functionality here
  }
  ```
- Now here is the trick that steals the show, When you receive a notification in your MainActivity pass the bool as true in the load app method and pass the data if anything is present in the notification.Something like this:

  ```
  LoadApplication(new App(true,*yourData*))
  ```

**Note:** I have defined the optional parameter in the constructor so you can even use the empty app constructor to make it work;

**Update:**

```
private bool IsNotification=false;
private object NotificationData;
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);    
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NOTIFICATION RECEIVED", p.Data);
       NotificationData = p.Data;
       IsNotification=false;
       DependencyService.Get<IToast>().DisplayTost("opened notifications");           
    };
   if(IsNotification)
    LoadApplication(new App(IsNotification,NotificationData)); 
   else
    LoadApplication(new App());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll revert.

Comment: Oh yeah, one more thing I think you need to call this `FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);` before the load application method.

Comment: Your code always opening NotificationPage without sending notification, when I tap on App icon. For more information check my edits.

Comment: I have edited my answer with how the code should be take a look

Comment: I appreciate your help.  However this issue was related to plugin not our code. I have posted answer have a look. Thanks a lot.